# Colormap drawing order in parametric 3D tube

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, 3d

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267164/120853), I am trying to draw a parametric tube in a PGFplots 3D-plot:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=2,
            samples y=20,
            y domain=0:360,
            colormap/blackwhite
        ]
        ({sin(y)}, {x}, {cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image: broken 3d tube]

I am not sure, how to fix the drawing order of the colormap. It seems quite glitchy as-is.

Putting the domain so that it joins at the bottom, where in the current view there is no overlap of the tube with itself, fixes it (`y domain=-70:290`):

[image]

The issue with that is of course, that once the current view changes, we have to manually adjust the `y domain`.

How can the colormap overlaying itself be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pgfplots` is very smart but sometimes one needs to help it a bit. Here you need `z buffer=sort`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=2,
            samples y=20,
            y domain=0:360,
            colormap/blackwhite,z buffer=sort
        ]
        ({sin(y)}, {x}, {cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was not planning on answering this question myself, but I found the key `z buffer` in the PGFplots manual, in Section 4.6.5. *Mesh Plots*.

Supplying it gives

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=2,
            samples y=20,
            y domain=0:360,
            colormap/blackwhite,
            mesh/interior colormap name=hot,
            z buffer=sort
        ]
        ({sin(y)}, {x}, {cos(y)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which works and also allows correct plotting of an interior colormap for the mesh:

[image]